# Angular Bisector of Planes

Tags: geometry

> **Recall that:** Let $\pi_1=a_1x+b_1y+c_1z+d_1=0$ and $\pi_2=a_2x+b_2y+c_2z+d_2=0$ be two intersecting planes with $d_1>0$ and $d_2>0.$ Then the angular bisectors of the planes $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are given by $$\frac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1z+d_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2+c_1^2}}=\pm \frac{a_2x+b_2y+c_2z+d_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2+c_2^2}}$$

This is clear to me. But my questions are as follow:

**Question 1:** In the proof of the angular bisectors,  where do we use the assumption $d_1>0$ and $d_2>0$?

**Question 2:** What happens if either or both $d_1=d_2=0$?

**Question 3:** What happens if $d_1>0$ and $d_2<0$ or $d_1<0$ and $d_2>0$?

Can any one explain this clearly?

Comment: The bisectors are exactly the same. Standardizing the equations of the planes in some way allows you to tell which bisector is which.

Comment: what about question 2

Answer (score 1):

The signs of $d_1$ and $d_2$ don't actually matter in the formula. If either one is negative, we can just as easily invert the equation of the plane accordingly. For example, if $d_1 < 0$, then $d_1 = -|d_1|$, and we can instead define
$$ \pi_1 : -a_1x - b_1y - c_1z + |d_1| = 0 $$

The only time when the distinction is important is when you need you tell which bisector is which, as @amd has pointed out. I suspect your text will tell you which plane the $+$ sign represents and which sign the $-$ sign represents. Once we know this for the case $d_1,d_2>0$, then we can tell for other cases from inspection.

---

I do agree that this is ambiguous when either or both of the constant coefficients are zero. Perhaps a better way is to standardize the sign of the dot product of the two normal vectors, i.e.

$$ (a_1,b_1,c_1)\cdot(a_2,b_2,c_2) = a_1a_2 + b_1b_2 + c_1c_2 < 0 $$

This ensures the the angle between the two vectors is always acute, thus the sum of the two vector (minus sign in the equation) represents the bisector plane between the smaller angle, the the difference (plus sign in the the equation) is the other one.

Now you might ask what happens when the dot product is zero (the two planes are exactly perpendicular). Then you can standardize it so that one of the coefficient pairs is both positive, i.e. $a_1,a_2 > 0$. This depends on the specific problem, and why you'd need to tell them apart to begin with.